Original Record Isn't Reloading After Update
I have a customers page with an edit button. I can click the edit button, it loads the customers_edit.php page and I can edit the customer.  When I click save, it grabs the customerID as the updateID and attempts to reload the customer_edit page with the updateID in the address bar but it gives me a "is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" page.  The address in the address bar is correct and if I simply click in the bar and hit enter, it loads the desired customer page.  When I manually load the edit page, the edits have saved.  What might I be missing here to get the page to re-load after updates on it's own?
Here is the code:
<?php
.....


    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        header('location:../login.php');
    }




$sql = "SELECT * From Customers

           WHERE CustomerID ='$CustomerID'
"
;


$result = $conn->query($sql);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($result);die;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}


/*Update ccustomers table*/
$userName=explode('@',$_SESSION['user']['firstname']);
$userName=$userName[0];


if(!empty($_POST)){
   

    //DateEdited
    $Notes=$conn->real_escape_string($row[0]['Notes']);
    $NotesBilling=$conn->real_escape_string($row[0]['NotesBilling']);
    $company=$conn->real_escape_string($row[0]['Company']);
//    $billedAs=$row[0]['BilledAs'];
    $customerSource=$row[0]['CustomerSource'];
//    $customerType=$row[0]['CustomerType'];
    $customerStatus=$row[0]['CustomerStatus'];
    $donotcontact=$row[0]['donotcontact'];
    $dcpgreeting=$row[0]['dcpgreeting'];
    $dcpemailgroup=$row[0]['dcpemailgroup'];
    $shareddrive=$row[0]['shareddrive'];

    if($_POST['Notes'] !=''){
        $Notes=date('m/d/Y h:m'). ' '.$userName .'\r\n'.$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Notes']).'\r\n'.$conn->real_escape_string($row[0]['Notes']);
        //$Notes=$conn->real_escape_string($Notes);
    }
    if($_POST['NotesBilling'] !=''){
        $NotesBilling=date('m/d/Y h:m'). ' '.$userName .'\r\n'.$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['NotesBilling']).'\r\n'.$conn->real_escape_string($row[0]['NotesBilling']);
        //$NotesBilling=$conn->real_escape_string($);
    }

        $company=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Company']);

//    if($_POST['BilledAs'] !=''){
//        $billedAs=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['BilledAs']);

//    }


    if($_POST['CustomerSource'] !=''){
        $customerSource=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['CustomerSource']);

    }

//    if($_POST['CustomerType'] !=''){
//        $customerType=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['CustomerType']);

//    }

    if($_POST['CustomerStatus'] !=''){
        $customerStatus=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['CustomerStatus']);

    }

    if($_POST['donotcontact'] !=''){
        $donotcontact=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['donotcontact']);

    }  

    if($_POST['dcpgreeting'] !=''){
        $dcpgreeting=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dcpgreeting']);

    } 

    if($_POST['dcpemailgroup'] !=''){
        $dcpemailgroup=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dcpemailgroup']);

    } 

    if($_POST['shareddrive'] !=''){
        $shareddrive=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['shareddrive']);

    }               

   // echo "<pre>";print_r($Notes);die;
    $currentDate=date('Y-m-d');

    //$updateSql="UPDATE Customers SET Notes=mysqli_real_escape_string($Notes),NotesBilling=mysqli_real_escape_string($NotesBilling) WHERE CustomerID ='$CustomerID' ";
    $updateSql="UPDATE Customers SET Notes='$Notes',NotesBilling='$NotesBilling',Company='$company',CustomerSource='$customerSource',CustomerStatus='$customerStatus',DateEdited='$currentDate',donotcontact='$donotcontact',dcpgreeting='$dcpgreeting',dcpemailgroup='$dcpemailgroup',shareddrive='$shareddrive' 
                 WHERE CustomerID ='$CustomerID' ";
    $conn->query($updateSql);      

     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
    if ($conn->error) {
        printf("Error message: %s\n", $conn->error);die;
    }
    }
  

//echo "<pre>";var_dump($saved);die;
?>


please use parameterized prepared statements in all your db queries

First step is to find out exactly what caused the 500 error. See the duplicate for details.

Do you really believe he CustomerID send by the user? With this concept I can edit every foreign user record.

Thanks for the error checking information. That helped.
